# Убрать дубли страниц opencart

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, opencart

Убрать дубли страниц opencart.
Чтобы  `https://site.com/subcategory` редиректило на `https://site.com/category/subcategory`.
И страницы подкатегорий открывались только когда в url указана родительская категория.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант в контроллере сделать редирект.

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('controller/action', '', 'SSL'));
```

Второй вариант связан с настройкой mode_rewrite. Правило, которое необходимо добавить .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=OLDPAGE$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.ru/NEWPAGE? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: $this->redirect($this->url->link('controller/action', '', 'SSL'));
этот вариант поможет для всех сразу?
в htaccess прийдется для каждой подкатегории писать запрос?

Comment: первый вариант для всех сразу не подойдёт. Для каждого урла должен быть редирект. Во втором случае можно попробовать регулярку сделать, ну например, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}$ RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.ru/category/? [R=301,L]`